What does 腕鳴らしに殺されてくれ mean
For context. The character is introducing herself to the villain. After she states her name, she wields a sword made from the bones of someone she just killed and says this before engaging in a fight with the villain:

腕鳴らしに殺されてくれ！

Here's what I know. 殺されてくれ means "get killed for me". What I'm struggling with is the 腕鳴らしに part. 腕 means "arm", and 鳴らす is "to ring", "to sound", basically to suddenly emit a loud noise. The masu stem + に would make 鳴らす into an adverb to 殺されて. So would that mean "get killed in a sudden loud noise-like manner for me"? How does 腕 fit into this sentence? Is there an omitted particle after it? I'd like to know what this sentence means, as well as how it all comes together.

I believe this is simply a misuse of 肩慣らし ("warming up"). There is a well-known set phrase 腕が鳴る, which is something said before a battle and does look somewhat similar to 腕鳴らし. However, 腕が鳴る is a phenomenon that occurs involuntarily, and it does not make sense to say 腕鳴らしに ("for/as an 腕鳴らし") as if you are intentionally trying to cause a noise from your arm. It seems likely that the person who wrote it mixed up the two phrases by mistake.

EDIT: Now that Gui Imamura pointed out, I recalled 腕を鳴らす exists as the transitive version of 腕が鳴る. However, 腕を鳴らす is used in contexts where someone is eagerly awaiting a big event, such as a battle (see "待ち構える" in the definition). I don't think it is used when actively challenging someone to a fight. Its second definition (名声を広める) is also a common meaning, but I've only seen it in the form "(～として)腕を鳴らしている". Therefore, I still feel it is more likely that this expression is a misuse of 肩慣らし. Recently, just because it's a professionally published manga doesn't mean we can say it's error-free...
BCCWJ had no examples of 腕鳴らし, so I checked Google search results and found several examples of it, including 腕鳴らしにはちょうど良かった. It seems to me that most of them are likely used with the same meaning as 肩慣らし.

This was from a manga, and the furigana on the side read うでな for the 腕鳴. I think this mixing up of phrases might have been an intentional artistic choice.

@DietSouda Please see the edit.

Fair enough. To be quite honest, the "機会を待ち構える" part didn't quite fit in, but I felt like I'd seen 腕鳴らし somewhere else and it didn't sound weird at all to me. On a second thought, and after having read your edit, I too think it to be a probable misuse of 肩慣らし.

@GuiImamura Anyway, thank you for reminding me of the transitive version of 腕が鳴る. FWIW, the only example of 腕を鳴らす in BCCWJ is "山スキーを楽しむべく腕を鳴らして天気待ちしているOL", which I think is a correct use of the idiom.

I've removed my answer to avoid confusing anyone.
